# Compare tables in different environments for column changes

Tags: sql-server, compare, multiple-columns

So I have two environments Test and Prod.

I have the same table in both environments. Both tables have quite a few columns.

How can I check if there are any columns in one table that aren't in the other, without comparing them separately? Any tricks or tips to this?

I tried doing

```
SELECT t.name as table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_ID) as schema_name,
c.name as column_name
from sys.tables as t
inner join sys.columns c on t.object_ID = c.object_ID
WHERE t.name like '834daily%'
```

But it didn't return anything.

Both SQL DBs are on different Servers, `.100` is test and `.110` is prod.

I'm sure there's a simple way to do this in SQL alone, but not sure exactly the best approach. I've also done things like writing out a `CREATE TABLE` statement but I can never get them side by side to do a direct comparison. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do something like this:

**LINKED SERVER:**

```
--find your both test and prod server name by running query below
select * from sys.servers


--query to find column name that exists in one environment and not in other
--replace SERVERNAME AND DATABASENAME as needed
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM SERVERNAME.DATABASENAME.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS prod 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName'
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM SERVERNAME.DATABASENAME.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS test
WHERE prod.TABLE_NAME = test.TABLE_NAME);
```

**NON-LINKED SERVERS:**

```
--replace SERVERNAME AND DATABASENAME to match yours
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
        ,TABLE_NAME
    FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=SERVERNAME;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 
    'SELECT COLUMN_NAME,TABLE_NAME FROM DATABASENAME.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
     WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''YOURTABLENAME''')
    ) AS prod
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM SERVERNAME.DATABASENAME.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS test
        WHERE prod.TABLE_NAME = test.TABLE_NAME
        );
```

Comment: The servers are not linked.

Comment: @Hituptony Please check out my updated answer and see if it helps any.